# How do I update multiple records in a table to remove a second word from a column?

Tags: sql-server

This is the question asked in the homework

Write SQL to remove `'Airlines'` from any carrier that has it. For example, if `'Delta Airlines'` is in the table, your SQL should change that value to just `'Delta'`. This must be a single query that addresses all records that have `'Airlines'` in them, and should fix them all at the same time. It must be written with the assumption that other records containing `'Airlines'` could exist, and if they did exist, it should address them as well.

The table I currently have for airlines has 6 airlines listed and only two contain the word airline. In the table there are two columns `AirlineID` and `AirlineName`. How do I delete the second word from the `AirlineName` column?

I tried

```
Update Airlines
Set AirlineName = 
  Case
       When AirlineName = 'Southwest Airlnes' Then 'Southwest'
       When AirlineName = 'Frontier Airlines' Then 'Frontier'

       End
```

However after running this it set every record in the AirlineName record to NULL.

Comment: Two hints....REPLACE and LIKE. Thank you for admitting this homework. Most people will help guide you but not give you an answer as you need to figure that out on your own.

Comment: I entirely agree. I would just add one other hint ... Before trying to do an update statement, check first that you can do a SELECT with only the records that have Airlines and also with this field as it should be amended.

Comment: In addition to the advice above, you should also study the `Case` structure more carefully.  Almost all of mine have an `Else` clause at the end.  Also, +1 kudos for admitting that this is homework.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I  was able to piece it together and figure out the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

Update Airlines 
Set AirlineName = Replace (AirlineName,'Airlnes','')

And, you can also try this without using the replace function. In this below query do not need to pass the hardcoded string like 'Airlnes'.

Update Airlines 
Set AirlineName = SUBSTRING(Airlinename,1,(CHARINDEX(' ',Airlinename + ' ')-1))

Comment: Please read the comments left by other users. The OP admitted that this was homework. SO does not do people's homework for them. We hint, we nudge, we correct when they get it wrong. We do not do their work for them.